# how to create multiple form elements dynamically inside a form using symfony2 and doctrine2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form which is linked to 3 tables in a database.

The first table's  Form has an access to the second table's form which has access to the third form's type.

The way it works is as follows:

**firstType has following structure**

```
$builder->add('second', new secondType())
```

**secondType has following**

```
$builder->add('third', 'collection', array(
    'type', new thirdType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
))
```

**The thirdType:**

```
$builder->add('a')->add('b')
```

Of course the firstType and secondType has more elements and firstType is linked with secondType via a onetoone mapping and secondtype is linked with thirdtype via a onetomany mapping.

Above structure is so that i can map many instances of third table with 1 instance of second. Now the problem I have is that i cannot access the third table in a twig form. The error I am getting is

> **Method "a" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in x.html.twig at line 120**

I am trying to access it like this:

```
{{ form_label(form.second.third.a) }}
```

The same format works for elements of second. e.g.

```
{{ form_label(form.second.a_2) }}
```

I tried to follow:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/form_collections.html
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/collection.html

without success.

Comment: in twig you can always use `{{ dump(variable) }}` function to see whats going on, when you are stuck.

Comment: when i dumped the third, i got this:
FormView {#1129 ▼
  +vars: array:30 [▶]
  +parent: FormView {#962 ▶}
  +children: []
  -rendered: false
}

It shows no children. which is wierd

Comment: but it still doesn't solve the problem i have. When i do not use collection form type, i can access the third form's elements, but that doen't helps me in making the form dynamic

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that second has a collection of third so you need to iterate over form.second.third and then for each element you can get the "a" element. I have never showed embed form in that way but you could try something like:

```
{% for element in form.second.third %}
   {{ form_label(element.a) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: how would the for loop work if we do not know how many elements user wants to generate dynamically?

Comment: Well that's why I say that never used it in that way. What you need to do is add one single third element to the second before create all types, and show that to the user with the options of add more element as cookbook say. In twig just print the form_row(form.second.third) and only one "third" will be shown.

Comment: Also the foor loop don't need to know how many elements are, just print all of them.